# The singular term in the operator product of two fermion operators

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

Consider an operator product $\bar{\psi}(x+\epsilon)\psi(x)$ in which
$\psi(x)$ is the fermion field operator in QED. We want to compute
the singular term in $\bar{\psi}(x+\epsilon)\psi(x)$ in the limit
$\epsilon\rightarrow0$. In Peskin's book, an introduction to quantum
field theory (page 660), the leading singular term ``is given by
contracting the two operators using a free-field propergator'' as
follows,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{contraction of }\bigg(\psi(x+\epsilon)\bar{\psi}(x)\bigg) & = & \int\frac{d^{4}k}{(2\pi)^{4}}\frac{i\gamma\cdot k}{k^{2}}e^{-ik\cdot\epsilon}\\
 & = & -\frac{i}{4\pi^{2}}\gamma\cdot\partial\bigg(\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}\bigg)\\
 & = & -\frac{i}{2\pi^{2}}\frac{\gamma\cdot\epsilon}{\epsilon^{4}}
\end{eqnarray*}

Question: why the leading singular term is given by contracting the
two operators ?